# Не могу найти номер элемента массива

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно, что бы из массива копировалась только та часть, которая начинается с индекса элемента где ошибка, код ломается на моменте получения этого самого номера

```js
const data = {
  test: "1",
  '-test2': "2",
  test3: "3",
  test4: "4",
  test5: "5"
} // Данные

var albhabet = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'
// Проверяем по этой фигне данные, если первый симво не число - удаляем из массива

var correctBranchData = JSON.stringify(data)
//получаем обьект данных 

correctBranchData = correctBranchData.replace('{', '')
correctBranchData = correctBranchData.replace('}', '')
const arrData = correctBranchData.split(',')
//делаем из этого обьекта массив

arrData.map((item) => { // делаем проверку для каждого элемента массива
  const element = item[1].split(',') // длеаем массив из первой буквы каждого элемента

  function checkArr() {
    return albhabet.includes(element) // проверка возвращет true или false
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
    // получаем номер элемента над которым совершаем проверку 
    const number = i++ // Вот тут я застрял 
      if (checkArr()) {
        console.log('Все ок')
        return item
      } else {
        console.log('Удаляем')
        console.log(i)
        const sliceOne = arrData.slice(number)
        const sliceTwo = arrData.slice(sliceOne.length)
        console.log(sliceOne)
        console.log(sliceTwo)
        break
      }
  }
})
```

Comment: Из формулировки не до конца понятно, какой именно результат нужно получить для приведенного объекта `data`.

Comment: Что-то много лишнего кода... `['"test":"1"', '"test2":"2"', '"test3":"3"', '"test4":"4"', '"test5":"5"']` — такой массив строк должен получиться на выходе? Или вовсе удалить test2 ? И вы это сделали, потому что нужен был именно массив или просто как промежуточный результат, чтобы собрать это обратно в объект? (тогда массив вовсе не нужен, операции можно выполнять прямо в объекте)

Comment: вы верно поняли должен получиться ['"test2":"2"', '"test3":"3"', '"test4":"4"', '"test5":"5"'], без '"-test":"1"' - у него в начале "-", поэтому проверку не проходит

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = {
  test: "1",
  '-test2': "2",
  test3: "3",
  test4: "4",
  test5: "5"
};


let result = Object.keys(data)
  .filter(key => /^[a-z]/i.test(key))
  .map(key => {
    let obj = {};
    obj[key] = data[key];
    return obj;
  });
console.log(result);
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ

Comment: пометьте ответ принятым, если он вам помог